# need to pass some content in header in get request of JSON using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring

I need to consume the rest service using my rest client.
From the 1st URL, need to fetch some content (in this case it is a JSON web token).
And in the 2nd URL, need to pass this token in request header. Please help me achieving the same.
Just to note, the 1st URL is with POST and whereas the second URL is with GET request.

With the help of RestTemplate api, I am able to get the response body and response header when passing the first URL in method PostForObject(url, map, String.class). From Response header, I am able to get the details about pragma, cache, content-type, server, content-length, expires etc but not able to fetch the JWT string (Json Web Token). I need to get the JWT as I need to pass this into the request header of 2nd URL (GET) to get the actual information.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Path Params to fetch data from the URL and use the same to add to a different URL- 
Example:

```
@Path("/{taskId}")
public Task get(@PathParam("taskId") Long taskId)
{
    // Handles GET on /tasks/{taskId}. Returns a single task for the given taskId.
    return taskService.find(taskId);
}
```

for more details visit : http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path

If this helps you, mark as answer

Comment: Thanks for your help Kaushik but my case is little different. Let me explain a bit. As I get the response from 1st url, I am to get details about all the response body and header (eg: cache, pragma, content-type etc) but not able to fetch the JWT string (JSON web Token). I need to get the value so that I can pass this in to the header of 2nd url to get the actual information. I am updating my question also.

Answer (score -1):

I could get this info, I am posting the same as below in case someone needs the same.

```
Collection<List<String>> headerContent = restTemplate.postForEntity(URI url,
    Object request, Class<T> responseType),getHeaders().values();
```